# Scala Comet and Mobile Applications

Tags: android, ios, mobile, comet, webos

I'm exploring using Scala with its [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)) facilities for my next project and was curious if anyone had experience using Comet (not necessarily Scala) with:

- WebOS
- Android
- iOS

All these phones are WebKit, which should mean that my Chrome tests would work equally well, but I don't know how long-polling connections work over 3G (or whether they eat the battery alive).

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the answer to [Android service with long living HttpConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5505801/808940)

It seems to suggest empirical evidence of battery munching, albeit for a slightly different reason.