# Android service with long living HttpConnection

Tags: android, service, comet, wakelock

```
I am tring to develop a project that connects to
```

a comet server with long living
 connections. i do this job in a service. 
But when android device goes to idle mode, the thread i started from service stops working and do not close connections or try a new connection.

is there any method that i should use for this stuff.

Comment: Ideally, you would switch to use C2DM.

Answer (score 0):

Using PowerManager.WakeLock solved my problem. I know, it kills baterry usage but, i had to use a long living service.